# Bootstrap/Angular modal no longer works after opening and closing once

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page which opens a modal that asks for user confirmation when making an edit to something on the page. If the user chooses "Cancel" button in the modal, the modal closes fine, but then refuses to re-open with the same link. The following error gets thrown if the modal link is clicked again:

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
at $parseFunctionCall (https://localhost:44310/js/angular.js:12346:15)
at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (https://localhost:44310/js/angular.js:21438:17)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (https://localhost:44310/js/angular.js:14401:28)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (https://localhost:44310/js/angular.js:14500:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44310/js/angular.js:21443:23)
at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:6466)
at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.add.r.handle (https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3:3241)
```

Here is the controller for the modal, very simple:

```
(function (angular, undefined) {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("app.edit")
    .controller("App.EditController", [
        "$modalInstance", "$scope", "editList",
        function ($modalInstance, $scope, editList) {
            $scope.thingsToEdit = editList;
            $scope.ok = function () {
                $modalInstance.close();
            };
            $scope.cancel = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
            };
        }
    ]);
})(angular);
```

The editList is used to display a list in the confirmation modal, the html of the page.

And the HTML for the modal is:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Edit</h3>       
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Please confirm the following edits: </p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="thing in thingsToEdit">{{thing}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="ok()">Confirm Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the JavaScript for the original page that opens the modal is:

```
$scope.edit = function (things) {
    $scope.editList = things;
    $scope.thingsToEdit = things;

    var editModal = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: "edit.html",
        controller: "App.EditController",
        resolve: {
            editList: function () {
                return $scope.thingsToEdit;
            }
        }
    });

    editModal.result.then(function () {
        var editUrl = //a valid url
        $http.post(editUrl, { cache: true })
             .success(function () {
                 console.log("edit successful");
             })
             .error(function () {
                 console.log("edit failed");
             })
    }, function() {
        console.log("edit canceled");
    });
};
```

Comment: Can we please add the HTML? Here's a plunkr that may assist you: http://plnkr.co/edit/vnNIRLeW5SvtlVO22SWh?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I added the HTML and the JavaScript for opening the modal. I took a look at the plunkr, it looks very similar to what I am doing. Still am unable to find the problem...

Comment: Check your dependencies perhaps? Did you add ui.bootstrap? ngAnimate? I would compare again to the plunker as the code you pasted looks fine so it could be in some other code that wasn't pasted.

Comment: I figured out a workaround, but I'm still not sure what the original problem was. I had to call an initialization of the edit list and then call a non-scope method which then opened the modal. Then, when the modal is closed, I dump the edit list.